# UDP or Unix Socket for efficient non blocking server?

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, nio

I am writing a server (Java based) which will be only called by program on the same host.

So, in term of performance & reliability, should I use UDP or just Unix Socket?

Answer (score 1):

UDP is not reliable.  I'm picking nits, but there is no guarantee of either delivery order or delivery at all with UDP.  Between two processes on the same host, this is probably never going to manifest as a problem, but it may be possible under extreme load scenarios.

There's also a lot more overhead in a UDP packet than there is in a Unix socket.  Again, this is unlikely to be a practical problem except under the most extreme load, and you'd have a lot of other load-related problems before that was a concern, because the overhead for both is nominal in modern computing terms.

If you're really worried about performance and reliability, stick with Unix sockets.

If you have any plan to distribute and load-balance it in the future, UDP will give you more flexibility if you need to support multiple hosts.

Having said all that, none of this is a practical concern these days.  Most services use TCP for even local communication, and then layer other services like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) on top of that.  You almost definitely should not be worrying about that level of performance.  Use software that makes your code easier to write and maintain, and scale up the system in the unlikely event that you need to.  It's easier and cheaper to throw new servers at problems than it is to spend man-hours re-engineering software that wasn't written to be flexible.

Also note that ZeroMQ (and other message queueing systems) will pick the most efficient transfer mechanism available.  For example, ZeroMQ will use IPC (inter-process communication) if possible, which is far faster than either UDP or Unix sockets, and it will also scale up to thousands of hosts worldwide over the Internet if you need that, and you basically won't have to change your code.

Never prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 0):

A unix socket will certainly spare you the overhead of context switching and encapsulation/decapsulation through the tcp/ip stack. But how perceptible that gain will be ? I think it depends on your requirements for performance and reliability and on the load you're expecting this server to handle.